# Remove port from sampler request which is coming from User Defined Variables

Tags: jmeter, httprequest, port

I want to remove port number which is coming from User Defined Variables for specific HTTP sampler request.

I am calling port dynamically in User Defined Variables, So if I update the variable to null before request, I am unable to set it dynamically after request

Comment: You can use different variable or update variable before and after request

Comment: True,
But the thing is I am calling port dynamically in User Defined Variables, So if i update the variable to null before request, i am unable to set it dynamically after request

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can use different variable, but for dynamically, For example for exchanging variable port with newPort in Sampler:

Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of request:

```
vars.put("tempVar", vars.get("port"));
vars.put("port", vars.get("newPort"));
```

And add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of request:

```
vars.put("port", vars.get("tempVar"));
```

Another option is to send all the URL in Path field without port and protocol and server name). e.g:

```
http://localhost/continue?test=test
```

Comment: Thanks mate.
Correct,
That is the same if i by pass the port for that specific request with a user defined variable as null(empty) or passing null(empty) in the request itself.
Is there any work around for this approach?